# Git basic workflow

Tags: git, push

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git push error '[remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked)

I am new to Git and trying to use it for a local grails project.
The steps I followed:

1. create the grails project
2. go to the project directory and `git init`
3. Add all the files in the project in staging area and commit.
4. The git status at the repo gives the below message

   ```
   BXX@BXX-PC /c/Work/Grails/projects/yyy/tables (master)
   $ git status
   # On branch master
   nothing to commit (working directory clean)
   ```
5. Trying to keep it as the master branch, make the changes by cloning the repo, and later push the changes back. For that
6. In my IDE, checkout the project (IntelliJ).This actually clone the project to another dir.
7. Make the changes and commit the project
8. Push the local changes to master.

   ```
   15:41:56.249: git push -v origin master
   Pushing to c:/Work/Grails/projects/xxx/tables
   remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master        
   remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository        
   remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent        
   remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match        
   remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
   ```

The cloned repo status is

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Please help me with understanding this. Is there a better workflow to follow. I may be able to initialize the repo through Intellij, and try to work on the main branch. Still not sure what is wrong above.

thank you.

Comment: Just push into different branch and then merge it: `git push origin master:foo`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First of all, you do not need to clone your local repository. You can use branches to divide development in the same repository.

Git is a Distributed VCS, and if you have experience with Subversion or CVS before it, you need to change your mind.

Git is a very agile and you can use different workflows with it. Cloning repositories is more needed for a team work, not for local development (IMHO).

Branches is a good alternative for you.

See. Let's set **master** branch of your repository for a **production-ready** code. Let's create another branch for **development**:

```
$ git checkout -b development master
```

Now you are working on the **development** branch.

You could use different branches for each feature you want to develop. It's very easy and helpful.

Let's imagine you want to implement some new feature, you need to create a new branch:

```
$ git checkout -b newfeature development
```

Now you can work with your code, add files, commit and so on.

Next you need to **merge** your new developed feature to the **development** branch:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "My last changes for the new feature"
$ git checkout development
$ git merge newfeature
```

Now your new code from the **newfeature** branch merged into the **development** branch.

For sometime in the future when you decide that your code in the **development** branch get some milestone, you could merge all the changes from **development** to **master** branch.

It's a very basic workflow, it can be helpful for the many branches.

My advise for you now: read more about git, branching, stashing (very-very-very helpful for quick fixes). And after some time you will get a great effort from using git.

Good luck.

Comment: thank you so much for your step-by-step answer.. you are absolutely right, I still think traditional SCM model. I only used ClearCase and Microsoft SourceSafe before... so, u imagine :-) ... your answer help me to put together many concept i read about git.. thanks a lot...

Answer (score 45):

The problem is that you're trying to push to a non-bare repo. A non-bare repo is one which has an associated working tree (that is, the files are actually checked out to disk). By default, Git won't let you push to a non-bare repo; pushing to a non-bare repo only updates Git's internal data structures, and does *not* alter the working tree (the files on disk), which means that if you then go back to the repo you pushed to and start working on the files, you'll be working on older copies of the files. Naturally this will cause problems when you try to commit your changes.

The best way to do this is to push to a *bare* repository, which is one created by passing the `--bare` flag to Git when creating the repo:

```
$ mkdir new_repo
$ cd new_repo
$ git --bare init
```

Of course, the bare repo won't have any files checked out, so you can't actually work it in (you'll have to clone it first).

If you're just using a Git repo for local development (and not sharing or serving the Git repo), you don't *have* to have a remote repo to push to; you can work on a single copy of a local, non-bare repo.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed reply.. I infact read some of your answers on similar issue on SO. I may follow your advise to use one local repo, and then clone whenever necessary. Still, is it a possibility that I checkin (commit) the first (master) repo, then try to push the cloned one. I am curious how someone can clone my repo and push it to the master in the later stage. I greatly appreciate your comment so I don't regret in the long term.. thanks again

Comment: Note: there is a case where pushing to a non-bare repo can be appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10731806/6309

Answer (score 10):

This is the clearest, most comprehensive description of a successful git workflow.  It covers basically what Sergey suggests, with the addition of some very hepful graphics.

[A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/git-model)

The author also suggests when you merge to include the `--no-ff` tag to keep record of the fact that you had a feature branch in history.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up here when trying to fix the same kind of problem, fortunately there is a much better answer out there:

[Git push error '[remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked-ou)

You should check that one out. Especially as it is pretty easy to end up in this circumstance. For me all I did was create a directory and git init it to make my new "shared repository". It was on a USB key because our network is completely locked down and we can't share a directory or access GitHub yet.

Then I copied all of our source into that directory, added it, committed it, and then cloned the resulting repository to my local drive so that one was now my origin. I figured I could later make GitHub remote and do away with the shared USB repository. However, my first change on the local drive and attempt to push to the remote (the key repository) gave me the message because the key repository wasn't "bare". All of the original files were out there still.

Consult the most highly rated answer on the linked to question to see what to do. The gist is that you set a flag in the shared repository so it thinks it is bare and then delete everything out of it except the .git subdirectory and your push will then work.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question that was asked. The other answers are full of useful git knowledge but yours got me past my immediate problem.