# Git push to refs/remotes/mine/master

Tags: git

I am tracking a remote repository, i.e. I have `refs/remotes/joe/master`.

I know would like to get joe's changes as soon as possible into my repository.
I don't want to use `fetch`, because I might not be at the computer when he commits. So I tell him: I might be out for shopping, so please just push your changes to `refs/remotes/joe/master`.
The reason I want his changes asap in my repo is that he turns off his computer in the evening, so I wouldn't be able to fetch his changes when I come back from shopping.

I know that joe should just setup a bare, public repository, but this is sort of an overhead.

Is pushing to `refs/remotes/joes/master` an okay thing to do in such a case?

Comment: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/42506/focus=42685 was what I was really looking for.

Comment: I completely missed your comment, so I have posted an answer detailing that thread (as well as a reference to another solution)

Answer (score 1):

"[best/simplest way to keep multiple (non-bare) Git repos in sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192552/best-simplest-way-to-keep-multiple-non-bare-git-repos-in-sync)" proposes to deal with that kind of contribution with a post-update hook.

However, there is a more straightforward solution:

As The [OP zedoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42645/zedoo) comments, the [thread on git push to a non-bare repo](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/42506/focus=42685) (written by Git maintainer Junio C Hamano, back in 2007) details:
(and it is a great example of **a case where it is appropriate to push to a non-bare repo**)

> > > receive-pack isn't updating the `HEAD` reflog as its updating the actual branch, not `HEAD`.
> > >       If you pushed instead to `HEAD` you should see the `HEAD` reflog entry too.
> >
> > What about splitting `HEAD` when you push to the underlying branch, and making `HEAD` a non-symref?
>
> I do not think any of the complication is needed, and I think somebody mentioned a **good example, which is a firewalled host that can only be pushed into**.
>   In that example, even though he knows he could fetch in reverse direction in the ideal world, the network configuration does not let him do so, **hence need for a push**.
>
> **To deal with that sanely, people who push between non bare repositories can just forget about pushing into branch heads**.
>
> **Instead, they can arrange their pushes to be a *true mirror image of their fetch* that they wish could do**.
>   To illustrate:
>
> On repo `A` that can only be pushed into, if you *could* fetch from repo `B`, you would:

```
$ git fetch B
```

> with something like this:

```
[remote "B"] fetch = refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/B/*
```

> But unfortunately because you can only push into `A` from `B`, you would run this on `B` instead:

```
$ git push A
```

> with:

```
[remote "A"] push = refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/B/*
```

> And after you perform your push, **you come to the machine with repo `A` on it, and remembering that what you did was a mirror image of "`git fetch B`"**, you would:

```
$ git merge remotes/B/master
```

> and you are done.
>
> **In other words, don't think of `refs/remotes/B` as something that is for the use of "`git fetch`".
>
>   Its purpose is to track the remote repository `B`'s heads**.
>   You maintain that hierarchy by issuing fetch in repository `A`.
>   You can issue push in repository `B` to do so as well.
>
> I push into a live repository almost every day.
>   My typical day concludes like this:

```
gitster$ git push kernel-org-private
gitster$ ssh kernel.org
kernel.org$ git merge origin
kernel.org$ Meta/Doit -pedantic &
kernel.org$ exit
... go drink my tea ...
```

> where
>
> 1. `gitster` is my private development machine
> 2. `kernel.org` is a machine made available to me by friendly k.org folks
> 3. `Meta` is a checkout of my '`todo`' branch and
> 4. `Doit` is a script to build all four public branches.
>
> I always leave '`master`' checked out on my `kernel.org` repository, and the push from my private machine is done with (I still use the non separate-remote layout):

```
Push: refs/heads/master:refs/heads/origin
Push: refs/heads/next:refs/heads/next
Push: +refs/heads/pu:refs/heads/pu
Push: refs/heads/maint:refs/heads/maint
```

> **So the first thing I do after logging in to `kernel.org` machine is to run "`git merge origin`" to bring the '`master`' up-to-date.
>
>   If you think of '`push`' being mirror image of '`fetch`' you would understand why.**
>   It is like issuing "git fetch" on `kernel.org` machine to retrieve the hot-off-the-press from my private machine and then "`git merge`" it (usually "`git pull`" would do that as a
>   single step).
>
> However, sometimes I accidentally leave '`next`' checked out.
>   If I find out that I left non '`master`' checked out, I would do "`git reset --hard HEAD`" before doing anything else, and I do not want my push to sometimes result in detached `HEAD` and sometimes not.
>   I do not want to lose the information which branch I was on last (because the next thing I would do is to find out on which branch `Meta`/`Doit` failed).
>   If I *were* annoyed enough by sometimes mistakenly pushing into the live branch, I would switch to separate remote layout and push into `remotes/origin/*` hierarchy, and there will
>   be truly nothing to worry about after that point.