# Problem with git push

Tags: git

I cloned a project over ssh, made some changes, commit it, and then trying to push changes back (by `$> git push`), but I'm getting an error: "remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master".

Why is that, and how to fix it?

Comment: The same error is mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked-ou and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670680/git-basic-workflow. Are they relevant?

Answer (score 6):

[You should only push to bare repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked-ou)

Answer (score 0):

There might be some changes applied to the remote branch after you checked it out.
If you are talking about single commit you made, and remote branch is master, then do:

```
git fetch origin
```

to fetch most recent changes

```
git rebase origin/master
```

to put your changes on top, and finally

```
git push origin master
```

The last command can be reduced to the one you used, but it is usually a good habit to specify where exactly you push the changes on the current branch.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've cloned a personal repository (where files are checked out etc.).

You can't push back to the currently checked out branch on the remote, which is `origin/master` in your case.

But you can create a new branch in your clone and push that one back.